# Do all human cells have all the same organelles?

Tags: cell-biology

I know that not all human cells have nuclei (erythrocytes eject theirs before they are fully matured), but do all human cells have all the other organelles? The two I'm particularly concerned with are the Golgi apparatus and lysosomes.

Comment: sperm often lack certain organelles, so are you including germ cells.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of an organelle in a cell is strongly connected with its main function. For example in red blood cells, to have maximum space for haemoglobin and hence oxygen storage, many of the organelles are not present such as nucleus, golgi complex, lysosomes, etc. Another example can be of liver cells or muscle cells having a very high amount of mitochondria and ribosomes for high ATP production and protein synthesis. Similarly, each cell is designed in the most efficient way that aligns with its main function.

The answer to your question is no. Not all cells have golgi complex or lysosomes.

One thing that is important here is that the presence of golgi complex is linked with the presence of lysosomes. If there are no golgi complexes, lysosomes are also not present there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that yes.

Here is more to read about:
https://bscb.org/learning-resources/softcell-e-learning/golgi-apparatus/
"is found in all plant and animal cells"

and explanation why so
https://sciencing.com/would-did-not-golgi-bodies-8657737.html

I am no expert in this but I was looking for it as well, I believe it is right.

Comment: This is wrong. Erythrocytes and thrombocytes do not have golgi complexes. OP asked if _all human cells have all the **other** organelles_, so he is including those blood cells that lack nuclei. Anyway even then, I would not be surprised if some cells don't have a golgi complex some of the time.